# Testing slob.c using malloc()

Tags: unix, memory-management, operating-system, malloc, heap-memory

I have altered slob.c so that it gathers stats on the last 100 small list allocations. I made necessary edits to make sure SLOB is being used.

I am running a test program that calls malloc() about 10,000 or 100,000 times on a size of 20 bytes.

But my SLOB test results immediately after the test program runs states that the average claimed size was 140 bytes (when I was expecting it to at least be somewhere near 20 bytes).

What am I doing wrong, is there a way to accurately test SLOB?

I am pretty sure that my stat collecting is accurate, as I have had a few professors check it out for me. This is my current test program:

```
int main()
{
    char * a ;
    int i ;

    for( i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        a = (char*) malloc(20*sizeof(char)) ;
        if(a == NULL) printf("NULL\n") ;
    }
    //Here I print the system call resulting stats for memory claimed and free memory
```

Comment: Is this kernel code or user code?  If it is user code, what call did you use to dictate the memory allocation strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer was actually correct:

```
char * a ;
int i ;

for( i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    a = (char*) malloc(20*sizeof(char)) ;
    if(a == NULL) printf("NULL\n") ;
}
```

This simple code can be used to test how the altered slob file allocates memory (considering you are gathering statistics within the slob file).